# how can I create a product detail page?

Tags: php

i would like to create detail page for my sschoold atabase project. The idea is when you click the added lecture, it should bring a detail page. I wrote some codes but it didnt work out.. when i clicked the selected lecture nothing happening (href which is in my coursecontroller.php doesnt work). My Codes are down below.

Thanks in advance

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">

    <form method="post" id="add-lecture-form" class="col-xs-6 ajax-form" action="Controller/CourseController.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control lecture-name-field" placeholder="Please enter a lecture name!!">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="create">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="add a lecture">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="col-xs-6">  </div>

    <div id="lecture-result">  </div>

</div>
```

**coursecontroller.php**

```
function getCourseListAsView() {

    $dbConfigObject = new DbConfig;
    $dbConnection = $dbConfigObject->getDBConnection();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
    $search_query = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

    $listview = "<ul class='course-list'>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {
        //title column in db
        $listview .= '<li class="course-list-element">'
                . '<a class="detail-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" href="Controller/detail.php">' . $row['title'] . '</a>'
                . '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary load-edit-form-button" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" data-title="' . $row['title'] . '" data-action="edit" href="Controller/CourseController.php">edit</button>'
                . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger action-button" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" data-action="delete" href="Controller/CourseController.php">delete</button>'
                . '</li>';
    }
    $listview .= "</ul>";

    echo $listview;
}
```

**detail.php**

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    echo $key, ' => ', $value, "<br/>n";

}

$id = $_GET['id'];

if($id) {
    echo '<p/>ID: ', $id, "<br/>n";
}
else {
    echo '<p>No ID parameter.</p>';
}
```

**custom.js**

```
    $('.detail-link').click(function(){
      window.location = 'Controller/detail.php';
    });
```

Comment: If you want to be able to access `$_GET['id']`, then you need to actually put a parameter by that name into the query string part of your link URLs. You only appear to be putting the record ID into the `data-id` attribute - but there it doesn’t “do” anything on its own, it would need some additional JavaScript to read that value and do something with it. (But since you have not shown any such JS code, I’m assuming there isn’t any.)

Comment: pass id in query string like . href="Controller/detail.php?id=<?php $row['id]; ?>"

Comment: @Gaurav - You forgot to actually echo the variable in your example ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. i have added my js codes above and updated my url href="Controller/detail.php?id=<?php $row['id]; ? . bu still when i click the element nothing happening,

Answer (score 0):

**option One:** 
Coursedetail.php

```
function getCourseListAsView() {

    $dbConfigObject = new DbConfig;
    $dbConnection = $dbConfigObject->getDBConnection();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses";
    $search_query = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

    $listview = "<ul class='course-list'>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {
        //title column in db
        $listview .= '<li class="course-list-element">'
                . '<a class="detail-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" href="Controller/detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">' . $row['title'] . '</a>'
                . '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary load-edit-form-button" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" data-title="' . $row['title'] . '" data-action="edit" href="Controller/CourseController.php">edit</button>'
                . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger action-button" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" data-action="delete" href="Controller/CourseController.php">delete</button>'
                . '</li>';
    }
    $listview .= "</ul>";

    echo $listview;
}
```

**Option two :** 
Don't change the course detail.php.

In custom.js file

```
$('.detail-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id =   $(this).data("id");
  window.location = 'Controller/detail.php?id='+id;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. <a class="detail-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" href="Controller/detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">' . $row['title'] . '</a>'    with this code i have received a synthax error message.

Comment: yes, when i changed my code as  '<a class="detail-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" href="Controller/detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">' . $row['title'] . '</a>' .

Comment: what is the error you got? If you select option one remove js code

Comment: Basically still the 'href' isnt functioning.